How to spin up n demo scratch orgs using CCI
Am currently using CCI successfully to manage a finite set of development scratch orgs for use within our development process leveraging the provided dev, beta, feature and release org templates - its a great framework! - however, my knowledge is limited and I cannot figure out if it is possible to generate n new orgs from a single template. To this point, if we create a new scratch org it deletes the previous of its type and we are essentially replacing it.
For example, if I were to receive 10 requests for a test org, I would like to be able to generate 10 new 'release' scratch orgs as requested and then pass the credentials of each new scratch org to a requester to then use, rather than continually refresh a single existing release scratch org. Is this possible? If so, any pointers to the correct commands to use would be really appreciated.

Sorted. Once I read the docs properly... 
https://readthedocs.org/projects/cumulusci/downloads/pdf/latest/ page 52.
